# What to use 2 t2.micro instances or just 1 t2.medium

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running EC2 t2.micro instance which I find insufficient. So, I want to use 2 such instances with a load balancer. Or, I can use a t2.small instance which has the features of 2 t2.micro instances. Would it be wise to run 2 instances and pay for load balancing or run just 1 double-sized instance and not pay for load balancing ? Or it can be the either way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you setup your solution to use 2 and the ELB, when you need even more power it will be easier to scale up. If you go with the single server solution, and you need more power down the road, you'll be faced with the same decision, so imo, better to setup for the scaling now.